# How to find the blank cells/cells only with spaces

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below VBA to find the blank cells from the columns A to AY. But this code is not helping me to identify the cells which have only spaces and no value available.

I have tried the below VBA code

```
Dim Blank As Range

For Each Blank In Range(Range("A11:AY11"), Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    If Blank = vbNullString Then
        Blank.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
Next Blank
```

Please help me to edit this VBA, so that it will identify the cells with spaces also.

Comment: If you change `If Blank = vbNullString then` to `if len(trim(Blank)) = 0 then`, does that get you what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following (a trimmed cell consisting of merely spaces will be empty)

```
Dim c As Range

With Workbooks(REF).Sheets(REF)
    For Each c In .Range(.Range("A11:AY11"), Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If Trim(c) = vbNullString Then
            c.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next c
End With
```